# How can I write update query for ms access having 3 tables?

Tags: c#

I have a Microsoft Access file which contains three tables named:

```
TAXINVOICE, InvoiceItems, products
```

`Taxinvoice` table contains:

```
INVOICENO,STATE,CUSTOMERNAME,ADDRESS1
```

`InvoiceItems` table contains:

```
InvoiceItemId,InvoiceNumber,ProductId,Quantity,UOM,UnitPrice,GrossAmount,VAT,VatAmount,TAX
```

`Products` table contains:

```
ProductId,ProductName
```

I want update query for based on `textboxvalue(InvoiceNo)`.

Comment: Which table you want to update ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), most notably [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).